# How do I get rid of this error message in my function?

Tags: c#

I have a function in a class but am receiving an error under "Withdraw", "not all code paths return a value". I thought adding a void would do the trick but can't seem to make it go away. Does know how I could revise my code? Here is the portion:

```
public virtual double Withdraw(double amount)
  {
     if (amount > balance)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Debit amount exceeded account balance.", "Insufficient funds!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
     }
     else
        return balance - amount;
  }
```

Comment: To all the answerers, if you read the question carefully, the return value is the balance. So return that, instead of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've declared that your function returns a `double`, it needs to do that whichever branch of the `if` gets taken.

You need to return a value from the `true` side of the `if`, after `MessageBox` returns, eg.:

```
if (amount > balance)
{
    MessageBox.Show(...);
    return balance;
}
else ...
```

Comment: I understand now. I need to return balance on my true condition of the if statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer but I think your Method is serving many purposes, the calculation and showing a message to the user, you should consider using two methods like this

```
public virtual double Withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (amount > balance)    
        throw new Exception("your message")        
    else
        return balance - amount;
}
```

code of the caller

```
try{
 Withraw(...)
}
catch{
 Your messageBox
}
```

Comment: +1, this is arguably the best answer as this appears to be business logic.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "code of the caller". The try catch seems to pretty much be the same thing above to me. Is that supposed to be some sort of exception handler?

Comment: @Jae In your code you are mixing two things, business logic `balance - amount` with UI logic `ShowMessage`, it would be much better if you split you method to have a clear separation between theme, do your business in the Withdraw method and let the caller (may be an event handler in the UI layer) do whatever it want when something goes wrong. one benefit of this approach is that your classes will be reusable in different technologies (WebForm, WinForm...) without nearly any modification.

Answer (score 2):

your ode should always return some value, in *any* condition, so

```
public virtual double Withdraw(double amount)
  {
     if (amount > balance)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Debit amount exceeded account balance.", "Insufficient funds!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return SOME_NON_VALID_VALUE_FOR_YOUR_APP; //or raise an exception,
        // depends on architecture 
     }

     return balance - amount;       
  }
```

considering the logic of the code provided, if `amount > balance` it's not correct , otherwise return computation.

Answer (score 2):

You line of code below does not return any value are main root cause:

```
if (amount > balance)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Debit amount exceeded account balance.", "Insufficient funds!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
 }
```

You should return a double value after `MessageBox.Show`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrn something after `MessageBox.Show` idealy `0`

```
  public virtual double Withdraw(double amount)
  {
     if (amount > balance)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Debit amount exceeded account balance.", "Insufficient funds!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return 0;
     }
     else
        return balance - amount;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is expected to returns a double but if `amount>balance` it will not.

```
public virtual double Withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (amount > balance)
    {
        //your messagebox code    
        return double.NaN; // or whatever you think is correct in this case.
    }
    else
        return balance - amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `double` value through your function.

But only mentioned in else part.

If , if(amount > balance) condition gets true, then also you will have to return the value.

See below code:

```
    public virtual double Withdraw(double amount)
      {
         if (amount > balance)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Debit amount exceeded account balance.", "Insufficient funds!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
         }
         else
            return balance - amount;

         return 0;
      }
```